# How to create node-like GUI which encapsulates Python code (Like Simulink)?

Tags: python, user-interface, jython

**What I want**

I want to create a GUI in Python which allows for a node-linkage interaction which encapsulates Python code/objects/functions. The following examples are the kinds of functionality that I would like to achieve.

- Blender node interface.

  [image]
- MATLAB Simulink block diagrams.

  [image]

**What I found**

- I found [Nodebox](https://www.nodebox.net/node/), with its [source](https://github.com/nodebox/nodebox) here. I will usually try learn off others repositories but its using Jython. I am not experienced with Java.
- Another example is [nodeworks](https://mfix.netl.doe.gov/doc/nodeworks/17.1.0/getting_started/first_tutorial.html) but the source code is not available, at least as far as I can tell.
- An [open-source alternative](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/cp3gtj/im_working_on_an_opensource_alternative_to/) to Simulink written in Python, although technically it has not been made open-source as of yet.

**My specific question**

Is there any package out there that allows me to create an interface with this functionality or **will I need to use Jython**? I'm prepared to learn if this achieves the best result.

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: @kevinlinxc unfortunately no great Python-based solutions, but since then I've picked up some web development. [React Flow](https://reactflow.dev/) is what I use for this now.

Comment: I kept looking and the best thing I could find was Ryven: 
https://github.com/leon-thomm/Ryven